# What is $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{G}, \mathbb{A}^1)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be an affine scheme and let $\text{Aff}(S)$ be the site of affine $S$-schemes. Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be a pair of sheaves on $\text{Aff}(S)$, and let $\mathbb{A}^1_S$ be the sheaf associated to the affine line via its functor of points.

The sheaf $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{G},\mathbb{A}^1_S)$ is a locally ringed space. My question is if it is possible to relate between this sheaf and the sheaves $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{A}^1_S)$ and $\text{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathbb{A}^1_S)$? More specifically, I suspect that similar to the category of schemes, there should be a way to construct a well defined map
$$\text{Hom}(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{A}^1_S)\otimes_{A(S)}\text{Hom}(\mathcal{G},\mathbb{A}^1_S)\longrightarrow \text{Hom}(\mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{G},\mathbb{A}^1_S)$$

which is an isomorphism. Is this true? How do I construct such a map?